# Calculus - Implicit Curve - rearranging derivative equation

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I'm new to this community, so please bear with me if I make a mistake following rules and conventions, and thanks in advance.

I'm currently learning - following along from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qb40J4N1fa4) ("Implicit differentiation, what's going on here? | Essence of calculus").

At 2:42 in the video timeline, the teacher mentions that the implicit curve equation $x^2+y^2=5^2$, which is then resolved into its derivative form: $2x\,\mathrm{d}x+2y\,\mathrm{d}y=0$ can then be rearranged to the form expression: $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = -\frac{x}{y}$. I wanted to understand how this rearrangement happened? I tried to explore this equation rearrangement: $2x\,\mathrm{d}x+2y\,\mathrm{d}y=0$ to $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = -\frac{x}{y}$ from online sources, but to no joy. 
By the way, I also tried to make the question more readable in terms of using the proper maths equation symbols syntax, using [this link](http://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), but I got an error message from this website saying that I don't have enough reputation score to post images in my question. So I hope I made this question as readable and clear as possible, with the limits I'm given. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that the method of implicit differentiation that Sanderson presents is [an abuse of notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio) used provide a more intuitive understanding of why it works. A more formal process would resemble the following $$ x^2 + y^2 = 5 \implies \frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2 + y^2\right) = \frac{d}{dx} 5^2 \\\implies 2x + 2y\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \implies 2y\frac{dy}{dx} = -2x \\\implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x}{y} $$

Comment: That makes total sense. Thanks Brian. What confused me first is the fact Grant Sanderson, plugged `dx` and `dy` to multiply by the derivatives 2x and 2y (but then he mentioned that he will explain more on this later in the video). Also the notation `dy/dx` is actually just to represent that we're trying to find out the derivative, but I confused it as being part of the equation workout. Also, thanks for editing my question in a better format. How do I mark your answer as "best answer" or give it a vote, since it's a comment?

Comment: Since my comment suffices, I incorporated it into an answer below so that this question can be removed the the unanswered tab.

Comment: Of course, naively one can just rearrange $2x\,\mathrm dx+2y\,\mathrm dy=0 \implies 2y\,\mathrm dy=-2x\,\mathrm dx \implies \mathrm dy=-x/y\,\mathrm dx \implies \mathrm dy/\mathrm dx = -x/y$.

Comment: $dy$ and $dx$ can be used as independent algebraic units when needed.  Some special handling is needed for higher order differentials, but you can still do it just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the method of implicit differentiation that Sanderson presents is an abuse of notation used provide a more intuitive understanding of why it works. A more formal process would resemble the following
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2=5&\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x^2+y^2)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}5^2 \\
&\implies 2x+2y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=0 \implies 2y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=−2x  \\
&\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=−\frac{x}{y}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Brian. I tried to upvote, but apparently I need at least score of 15 to be able to do that.